# How to run a command before a Bash script exits?

Tags: bash

If a Bash script has `set -e`, and a command in the script returns an error, how can I do some cleanup before the script exits?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
mkdir /tmp/foo
# ... do stuff ...
rm -r /tmp/foo
```

How can I ensure that `/tmp/foo` is removed, even if one of the commands in `... do stuff ...` fails?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Here's an example of using trap:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

function cleanup {
  echo "Removing /tmp/foo"
  rm  -r /tmp/foo
}

trap cleanup EXIT
mkdir /tmp/foo
asdffdsa #Fails
```

Output:

```
dbrown@luxury:~ $ sh traptest
t: line 9: asdffdsa: command not found
Removing /tmp/foo
dbrown@luxury:~ $
```

Notice that even though the asdffdsa line failed, the cleanup still was executed.

Comment: To whom it may concern: This will also be executed when someone uses Ctrl+D or `exit` to end the current bash session.

Comment: Using `trap cleanup EXIT`, the *cleanup* function will **also** execute if the "command in the script does **not** return an error".... On the other hand, using e.g. `trap cleanup ERR` will execute the *cleanup* function only when there is an error, it will not execute if there is no error . Further information in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261518/923560

Answer (score 16):

From the `bash` manpage (concerning builtins):

> trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]
>                 The  command  arg  is  to  be  read  and executed when the shell
>                 receives signal(s) sigspec.

So, as indicated in [Anon.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129923/bash-run-command-before-a-script-exits/2129932#2129932), call `trap` early in the script to set up the handler you desire on ERR.

Comment: Run `help trap` to see some help on the built-in.

Answer (score 14):

`sh` version of devguydavid's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130323/9645167).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cleanup() {
  echo "Removing /tmp/foo"
  rm  -r /tmp/foo
}
trap cleanup EXIT
mkdir /tmp/foo
asdffdsa #Fails
```

ref: [shellscript.sh](https://www.shellscript.sh/trap.html)

Comment: `POSIX` makes me smile. :)  Great teaching site you've linked to as well.

Answer (score 10):

From the reference for `set`:

> **-e**
>
> Exit immediately if a simple command (see section 3.2.1 Simple Commands) exits with a non-zero status, unless the command that fails is part of an until or while loop, part of an if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return status is being inverted using !. *A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.*

(Emphasis mine).

Comment: Might be worth adding "-E" when using "-e", see https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/

Comment: FWIW the trap also runs on a regular script exit, i.e. in the happy path

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it matters to you if it's before or after.

You can set a script to run immediately after closing with "trap". and then you can close the terminal.

**For Example;**

```
    trap  ./val.sh EXIT  #set command you want to run after close terminal 
    kill -9 $PPID        #kill current terminal
```