# What is the actual signal behind ERR

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling, signals, bash-trap

I've read in several places (including SO) that `-e` is considered "poor form" and is unreliable for exiting a script on any error. A better way to handle errors seems to be using `trap`, as such:

```
trap "echo there was an error; exit 1;" ERR
```

I can't seem to locate in the man pages what signal `ERR` is actually? I'm assuming it's `SIGQUIT` but I can't find for sure.

```
man 7 signal
```

only has the normal signals you would expect `SIGTERM SIGQUIT SIGINT`, etc.

```
man trap
```

has references to `ERR` signal, but doesn't seem to define it.

ex: "`A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.`"

```
man bash
```

is similar to `man trap` in that is makes references to `ERR` but doesn't define it from what I've seen.

What is the actual signal behind the shortcut `ERR`? (in normal signals as seen in `man 7 signal`).

I'd prefer to trap the actual signal name instead of the shorthand version, although I realize they would produce the same results (catching any error from a command in a script then throwing to the handler).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no signal corresponding to the `trap` signal specification `ERR`.

`ERR` is one of the signal specifications implemented internally by `bash`. [Note 1] If `trap ERR` is enabled, then bash will invoke the corresponding handler in exactly the same cases as  it would have exited had `set -e` been enabled. (Consequently, it is no more "reliable" then `set -e` but it is a lot more flexible.)

Other special `trap` names which do not correspond to any signal are `EXIT`, `DEBUG` and `RETURN`.

`help trap` will explain the meaning of these signal specifications.

---

**Notes:**

1. Actually, all of the signal specifications are implemented by `bash`, but most of them are implemented by `bash` trapping the signal and then executing the signal handler. The special ones just involve executing the signal handler.

Comment: From `help trap` I can see only the EXIT has a number indicated (0), but ERR, DEBUG and RETURN don’t.
If I understand correctly ERR is called if the errexit option is active and an error happen. Then the ERR signal it sent to the shell.
But, is the EXIT is sent too?
Which one (or both…) is sent if there is a `exit 2` (ie: if a voluntary exit with a return code not equal to zero) ?

Or, is the EXIT signal sent only when the return code of the bash process is 0, and in any other case, that’s ERR which is sent? And so, never both can be sent in any case?