# Explicitly trigger an ERR trap, bash

Tags: bash, error-handling

Is there some way for a bash script to explicitly trigger a trap that is looking for an ERR signal (which is a special signal that can be explicitly called via `kill`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261518/8236733)? 
Have a trap file of the form

```
#!/bin/bash
error() {#do stuff like alert people via email}
trap 'error ${LINENO} $tablename' ERR
```

and a script of the form

```
#!/bin/bash

# trap to catch errors
source '/home/mapr/etl_scripts/clarity/lib.trap.sh'

{#try stuff} || {#catch stuff; exit 1;}
```

I had thought that the `exit 1` would be enough to signal the trap, but this does not seem to be the case. Is there some other way to intentionally trigger the trap from within the script? Thanks.

Comment: did you try without the process group delim, i.e. `stuff || catch && exit 1` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Didn't work sorry, but thanks (basically testing by just putting `exit 1` before the whole try-catch section and nothing happened).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ERR` trap is only executed when a command run *by* the shell fails, not when the shell itself exits with non-zero exit status. For your case, you want to use an `EXIT` handler that tests the exit status.

```
trap 'rv=$?; if [ "$rv" -ne 0 ]; then error $LINENO $tablename; fi' EXIT
```