# Bash: Exit and cleanup on error

Tags: bash, error-handling

In my Bash scripts, I would like to make sure that the script exits as soon as there is an error. (E.g., to avoid a mistaken `rm -f *` after a failed `cd some_directory`.) For this reason, I always use the `-e` flag for bash.

Now, I would *also* like to execute some cleanup code in some of my scripts. From [this blog post](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/) I gathered

```
#!/bin/bash

cd invalid_directory
echo ':('

function clean_up {
  echo "> clean_up"
  exit 0
}
trap clean_up EXIT
```

The output I get is

```
./test.sh: line 3: cd: invalid_directory: No such file or directory
:(
> clean_up
```

so it does what's advertised. However, when using `-e` for bash, I'm only getting

```
./test.sh: line 3: cd: invalid_directory: No such file or directory
```

so the script exits without calling `clean_up`.

How can I have a bash script exit at all errors *and* call a clean up script every time?

Comment: It's better to handle error checking yourself than to rely on `set -e`. `cd invalid_directory || clean_up`.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Have you tried `trap clean_up ERR`?

Comment: @chepner Would you mind expanding on that? What's the benefit?

Comment: @chepner The scripts I have are usually much bigger than the above example. Handling it all manually is too tedious and error-prone for me to use.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, `ERR` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer It works for me. Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Biffen See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.

Comment: Your current approach is also error-prone. Use the approach that is at least predictable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: run command before a script exits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129923/bash-run-command-before-a-script-exits)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are never reaching the `trap` command; your shell exits before the trap is configured.

```
set -e
clean_up () {
    ARG=$?
    echo "> clean_up"
    exit $ARG
} 
trap clean_up EXIT
cd invalid_directory
echo "Shouldn't reach this"
```

However, it's better to [do your own error handling](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). You often want to vary your behavior depending on the exact reason *why* your script is exiting, something that is more complicated to do if you are running a single handler for *all* exits (even if you restrict your trap to `ERR` instead of `EXIT`).

```
cd invalid_directory || { echo "cd to invalid_directory failed" >&2; exit 1; }
echo "Shouldn't reach this"
```

This doesn't mean you have to abandon your `clean_up` function. It will still be executed for explicit exits, but it should be restricted to code that should run no matter *why* your script exits. You can also put a trap on `ERR` to execute code that should only be executed if you script is exiting with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Looks like you (the OP) intended `cd invalid_directory || exit`. Just checking -- otherwise, you will reach *"Shouldn't reach this"* every time.

Comment: That's what I would do for real (see my comment on the question). I'm just pointing out why the exit handler isn't executing. I'll update with that approach though.

Comment: That what I thought, but I was just scratching my head looking at the *"Shouldn't reach this"* line.

Comment: Oh, right; I left it implied that the code was being run with `set -e` :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @chepner! Do you know if it's possible to set the exit code to 0 on `EXIT` and 1 on `ERR`?

Comment: Use separate traps. `trap normal_exit EXIT; trap err_exit ERR`. In either trap, though, you may want to save the value of `$?` at the beginning of your trap in case you need it after any subsequent commands change its value.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the tip! Two separate traps really aren't necessary since the `EXIT` trap gets called eventually no matter what. If you'd change your example to `exit $ARG` with `ARG=$?` as the first line of `clean_up`, that'd cover my use case exactly.

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly assumed that the `EXIT` handler would be skipped if the `ERR` handler were triggered.