# Docker kill not working when executed in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, docker

The following works fine when running the commands manually line by line in the terminal:

```
docker create -it --name test path
docker start test
docker exec test /bin/sh -c "go test ./..."
docker stop test
docker rm -test
```

But when I run it as a shell script, the Docker container is neither stopped nor removed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

docker create -it --name test path
docker start test
docker exec test /bin/sh -c "go test ./..."
docker stop test
docker rm -test
```

How can I make it work from within a shell script?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Do you need `set -e`?

Comment: I don't think I need set -e but I don't think it hurts either. I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Unless the `exec` is returning something other than `0`, in which case the `stop` command will not be executed

Comment: That's a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `set -e` the script will exit when any command fails. i.e. when a commands return code != 0. This means if your `start`, `exec` or `stop` fails, you will be left with a container still there.

You can remove the `set -e` but you probably still want to use the return code for the `go test` command as the overall return code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker create -it --name test path
docker start test
docker exec test /bin/sh -c "go test ./..."
rc=$?
docker stop test
docker rm test
exit $rc
```

#### Trap

Using `set -e` is actually quite useful and catches a lot of issues that are silently ignored in most scripts. A slightly more complex solution is to [use a trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130323/1318694) to run your clean up steps on `EXIT`, which means `set -e` can be used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Set a default return code
RC=2

# Cleanup
function cleanup {
  echo "Removing container"
  docker stop test || true
  docker rm -f test || true
  exit $RC
}
trap cleanup EXIT

# Test steps
docker create -it --name test path
docker start test
docker exec test /bin/sh -c "go test ./..."
RC=$?
```